# WOE, in texting?

Tags: acronyms

I would like to know how the acronym WOE (which could also mean "what on earth"), came to mean a "friend or associate" in texting.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's within our remit to provide assistance with texting abbreviations, but maybe some kind soul will be willing to help you. lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Urban dictionary gives it as New Orleans slang: [Woe](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Woe), which is probably itself  a contraction of [Wodie](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wodie). The answers in [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/answers/comments/2xm4uk/what_does_drake_refer_to_when_he_says_the_6/) also seem to confirm it.

Comment: So wardie/wodie and not working on excellence? So New Orleans slang meaning associate or friend.